# Use Rails or Sinatra to bulid an Restful API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I have a question,
I need to create an API for an iOS app. This API will be private, only usable with the iOS App and I don't know what framework I must to use.
Rais? Sinatra? rails-api?

What is your recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are already familiar with Rails, I'd use the [Rails API gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api). It customizes Rails to behave as an API, and includes several useful functionalities like versioning and serialization.

Sinatra can be good for a very simple API, but usually, you'll end up adding most of Rails back into it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api), I would take a look to [Grape gem](https://github.com/intridea/grape)

You can use it on top of Rack, Sinatra and Rails.

Comment: I've been looking Gem Grape and looks very good. Just what I needed, the only thing is that now I have to try to put it together with my Rails project and I can't find much documentation on how to do, it's confusing ...